# How to render template into subdirectory with handlebars/ember

Tags: ember.js

Say I have a handlebars file stored in some_directory/some_template.handlebars

I want to render this template using render command so that I can hook it up to child controller.

I've tried:

```
{{ render "someDirectory/someTemplate" post }}
{{ render "some_directory/some_template" post }}
```

none of these works. If I move some_template.handlebars to root directory, then it works when I do:

```
{{ render "someTemplate" }}
```

but I would like to avoid this since I'm finding that the root directory is getting cluttered. It's worth mentioning I use the ember-rails gem.

Answer (score 0):

how are you packaging up the templates? are you sure it's even including the template in the browser?

You can find all the template names (keys) on Em.TEMPLATES object (see console in example below)

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ejolaWOQ/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I figured something out that works, you want to do:

```
<!-- note, did this in emblem, not sure if it translates to handlebars -->
{{ render 'nameOfController' someOptionalModel templateName='someDirectory/someTemplate' }}
```